# Include objects from other layouts android

Tags: android

I got a xml layout file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#474747"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/BtnSlide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/lin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="SteriaFIT Mobile"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:background="#41413F"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/some_layout_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_below="@id/some_layout_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow">
</View>
```

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF">
</ListView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="To Next Activity" />
```

I only want to get the `tabBar` layout from this file into another xml layout file, i do this by including after `@+id` this way:

```
<include android:id="@+id/tabBar" layout="@layout/horz_scroll_app" />
```

but it seems to me that this line of code will include the whole layout file?

**EDIT**

should mention that this method will also give me the `Button` with the id `button1`

**EDIT 2**

Ok, so after putting the `tabBar` inside a new layout file like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/tabBar"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#474747"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/BtnSlide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/lin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="SteriaFIT Mobile"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and included this to my orginal xml layout like this:

```
 <include  layout="@layout/tab_bar" android:id="@+id/tabBar" />
```

it seems to me that I cant register any `OnClickListener` to my `ImageButton` inside my `tabBar` layout. What I tried to do:

```
 View app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_bar, null);
 ViewGroup tabBar = (ViewGroup) app.findViewById(R.id.tabBar);

btnSlide = (ImageButton) tabBar.findViewById(R.id.BtnSlide);
btnSlide.setOnClickListener(new ClickListenerForScrolling(scrollView, menu));
```

Can anybody give me a hint=

Comment: Have you posted correct xml layout? You can't have more than one root elements in xml layout.

Comment: I have posted the xml correct. I can have more layouts inside a layout, can't I?

Comment: You can have more layouts in xml, but only one of them has to be the root element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include is used to include the whole xml file into the current layout. If you only want tabBar path then put them into a separate layout file then include them into the original view as well.

You will access the view normally:

```
LinearLayout tabBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabBar);
ImageButton btnSlide = (ImageButton) tabBar.findViewById(R.id.BtnSlide);
```

I believe, the whole putting views together part is done when compile. So you treat it as you normally would to a view in xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

Right, if provided layout file name is horz_scroll_app it will be included whole.
Checkout [this post by Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/)  for clear explanation about include.

Comment: Thats actually the post I read to find out how to get only objects by id.